# Microsoft Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, powerquery

I ve Azure SQL database with around 6 million rows of data. SQL queries takes very long time to respond. Although i am trying basic operation of filtering data. Is there any solution to reduce the execution time ? Thanks

Comment: Please read the [How to ask a good question FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to at a minimum provide a schema and query you are running. It could be as simple as adding the right index.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of factors that could impact performance on a SQL Azure Database, but they generally fall into two main categories. Those that are related to your data and those that are related to the Azure SQL DB.

**Data related factors include:**
Appropriate indexes on the data,
Query Optimization, etc.

**Azure Related Factors:**
Are you using an DB Edition with enough DTUs? DTUs range from 5 for Basic DBs to 800 for P3 DBs (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/)
Are you using the V12 preview which has significantly better performance on the Premium Editions. (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do to improve your query performance. We have around 20 million rows per Shard (Database). We ran into a few issues related to query performance, inefficient query plans chosen by Azure SQL and high Disk IO with regular DTU spikes. All this when were on a P4 Subscription.

- Statistics can quickly get out of date with large tables since SQL server internally waits for the table size to increase by 20% before updating statistics again. In addition to Auto Update Statistics being ON, it would be a good idea to schedule a job which automatically updates statistics periodically.
- Check if your indexes are fragmented. More the fragmentation, poorer the performance.
- Revisit your choice of indexes. More then number of columns in an index, lesser is your insert performance since, with every DML operation on the table, there are operations happening on each index to update it. If you definitely need all these indexes, rebuild them.
- Force Query Plan - use the query store to force the query optimizer to use the efficient query plan as opposed to the inefficient one. This should only be the last resort since the query optimizer generally does a good job of choosing the correct plan. Normally, all the above points if done properly, should fix the issue.